# Intersection of perpendicular tangent lines - generalization of directrix?

Tags: derivatives, locus

This is a funny little problem that I came up with.

For a differentiable function $f$, define a locus of points $P$ as follows:

- Let $m$ be an arbitrary tangent line to $f$, and let $n$ be another tangent line that is perpendicular to $m$. A point is in $P$ iff it is the intersection of $m,n$.

For a parabola, $P$ is the directrix (you can prove this with algebra or with geometry). But for other types of graphs, it gets a little weirder. Some examples:

- For $f(x)=x^3$, $P= \emptyset$ since $f'(x) \geq 0 \space \forall x$.
- For $f(x) = \sin(x)$, $P$ is a lattice of points consisting of the intersections of tangent lines having a slope of 1 and -1.

The specific problem I'm taking aim at is how to get an explicit description of what $P$ would look like for $f(x) = x^4$. I have drawn it in Geogebra and it looks like an inverted bell curve, which makes sense, but I can't get an actual equation to describe it. The same algebraic techniques used to show that $P$ will be the directrix when $f$ is a parabola end up with awful equations that I'm not even sure have a closed form solution.

The curve just looks so... I dunno... nice? I feel like there must be a much simpler answer than the pages of power functions that assail me every time I try this.

Comment: How did you draw the locus in geogebra?

Comment: By asking on a Geogebra forum and having someone else set it up for me >.<

Comment: Which is that forum?Any link?

Answer (score 1):

Very nice problem. As a novice algebraic geometer, this is my approach.

We start from the curve $C$ with equation $y=x^4$ on the plane $\pi$. If $(\bar x,\bar y)$ is a point of this curve, the line tangent to $C$ passing through this point is given by $(y-\bar y)=4\bar x^3(x-\bar x)$ which by using the equation $\bar y=\bar x^4$ can be rearranged into $y=(4\bar x^3)x+(-3\bar x^4)$.

Now, let's define a new space, called $L$. In this space, points represent what in the plane $\pi$ were lines: specifically, we represent the line in $\pi$ of equation $y=mx+q$ with the point $(m,q)$ in $L$ (these are not all the lines in $\pi$, but we don't care about those of the form $x=c$ as they are not tangent to $C$). The lines tangent to $C$ are thus represented by points of the form $(m,q)=(4\bar x^3,-3\bar x^4)$. Then $m^4=4^4\bar x^{12}$ and $q^3=-3^3\bar x^{12}$, so $3^3m^4+4^4q^3=0$: in other words, the set of lines tangent to $C$ are represented by a curve $C'$ in $L$, with equation
$$3^3m^4+4^4q^3=0$$
(this is the so-called dual curve of $C$, in the dual space $L$).

We're interested in finding the points of intersection of tangent lines of $C$ which are perpendicular. Of course, two lines represented in $L$ by $(m,q),(m',q')$ are perpendicular if and only if $mm'=-1$; we can represent pairs of lines as points of the product space $L\times L$, and we call the subset of pairs of lines which are perpendicular $V$. With a bit of algebra it is possible to show that the intersection as lines in $\pi$ (if it exists) of $(m,q)$ and $(m',q')$ is the point $$\Big(\frac{q'-q}{m-m'},\frac{mq'-qm'}{m-m'}\Big).\tag{1}$$
We thus get what is called a birational map $\varphi:L\times L\to \pi$, which associates to pairs of lines their intersection (if it exists). The curve we're looking for is the image $\varphi(V\cap C'\times C')$, that is, intersections of pairs of tangent lines of $C$ which are perpendicular.

Let's find this image: $V\cap C'\times C'$ is given by equations
$$\begin{cases}
3^3m^4+4^4q^3=0\\
3^3m'^4+4^4q'^3=0\\
mm'=-1
\end{cases}$$
and by some rearrangements we get that
$$q'^3=\frac{3^6}{4^8q^3}$$
and since we're dealing with real numbers, we can take the cube root of both sides to get
$$q'=\frac{3^2}{4^{8/3}q}=\frac{\mu^2}{q}$$
where $\mu=3/(4^{4/3})$.
Plugging this and $m'=-1/m$ in $(1)$ we get the point of $\pi$
$$(X,Y)=\Big(\frac{\mu^2m-q^2m}{m^2q+q}, \frac{\mu^2m^2+q^2}{m^2q+q}\Big).\tag{2}$$
Again, since we're dealing with real numbers, we can the cube root of both sides of the equation $3^3m^4=-4^4q^3$ to get, after some rearrangements,
$$q=-\mu m^{4/3}=-\mu t^4$$
where $t=m^{1/3}$.
Putting this in $(2)$ and after some algebra we finally get
$$(X,Y)=\Big(\mu\frac{t^{11}-t^3}{t^{10}+t^4},-\mu\frac{t^8+t^6}{t^{10}+t^4}\Big)$$
which is a parametric equation representing the curve we're interested in!

Finally, we can get an implicit equation by following the procedure specified [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parametric_equation#Implicitization). Using the software Sage with the following commands (I ignored the term $\mu$)

```
P.<x, y, t> = PolynomialRing(QQ, 3)
p = t^11 - t^3
q = -t^8 - t^6
r = t^10 + t^4

gcd = p.gcd(q).gcd(r)
pp = p.quo_rem(gcd)[0]
qq = q.quo_rem(gcd)[0]
rr = r.quo_rem(gcd)[0]

(x*rr-pp).resultant(y*rr-qq, t)
```

we get the equation
$$x^4y^2 + 2x^2y^4 + y^6 - 2x^2y^3 - 2y^5 - 2x^2y^2 - y^4 + 2x^2y + 4y^3 - y^2 - 2y + 1=0$$
which (ignoring the scaling term $\mu$) looks correct! (You might need to put something like $0.99$ instead of $1$ to actually see something).